# Moose Test Failures

Tags: perl, testing, moose

I'm trying to upgrade to the latest version of Moose and I am getting many test failures.

All of these errors appear related to metaclasses. I have also tried to install 2.0402 (that's what we have on our local mirror) and get the same errors. For example:

```
t/cmop/rebless_with_extra_params.t ............................ 
   Foo already has a metaclass, but it does not inherit Moose::Meta::Class
   (Class::MOP::Class=HASH(0x2be2070)). 
   at /home/cpoe/Downloads/Moose-2.0603/blib/lib/Moose.pm line 170.
```

[I've posted a gist of the full `make test` output](https://gist.github.com/3618458).

I am doing the standard "perl Makefile.PL; make; make test".

```
$ perl -v

This is perl 5, version 12, subversion 2 (v5.12.2) built for x86_64-linux
```

If anyone can suggest where to look to solve this error, or what other information I can provide to help diagnose it? My searches on Google have turned up nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is now resolved as it's a bug I have had before, but forgot about.

I had copied an old `.bashrc` to this box and had forgotten about this:

```
echo $PERL5LIB
lib:t/lib
```

The `t/lib` bit has caused install failures for me before on other modules and I should have remembered that.